# Jquery select next and prev img

Tags: jquery

I worked on a little jquery function but i'm a little stuck. What I'm trying to do is when I click on next and prev link to show me the next and previous img based on the img with the class="clicked". I know I can use the find() function but I dont really know how to implement it.

HTML

```
            <div class="thumbs_img">
                <a href="#p" class="prev">Prev</a>
                <img src="images/single_slider1.png" class="gallerythumbnail">
                <img src="images/single_slider2.png" class="gallerythumbnail">
                <img src="images/single_slider3.png" class="gallerythumbnail">
                <img src="images/single_slider4.png" class="gallerythumbnail clicked">
                <img src="images/single_slider5.png" class="gallerythumbnail"> 
                <img src="images/single_slider6.png" class="gallerythumbnail"> 
                <img src="images/single_slider7.png" class="gallerythumbnail">
                <a href="#n" class="next">Next</a>
            </div>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('.gallerythumbnail').click(function(){
        $('#homeprod').removeClass('clicked');
        $('.gallerythumbnail').removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });

    $('.showimagediv').show();
    $('.gallerythumbnail').on('click', function() {
        var img = $('<img />', {src    : this.src,
                                'class': 'fullImage'
                  });

        $('.showimagediv').html(img).show();
    });
});
```

Css

```
.showimagediv {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 474px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.gallerythumbnail{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width:80px; 
    height: 80px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.slider_prod{
    border: 2px solid #000;   
}
.thumbs_img{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.clicked {outline: 2px solid #fdb900;}
.fullImage{
    width: 750px;
    height: 474px;
}
.prev{
    background-image: url('images/arrow_left.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.next{
    background-image: url('images/arrow_right.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7mUmK/

Comment: Please include any relevant code and markup here so that the information can be preserved.

Comment: I edited the post with what I got so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution that doesn't hang your browser when you're on the first image and click "Prev" or on the last image and click "Next"

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    if(!$(".clicked").is(".gallerythumbnail:last"))
    {
        $('.clicked').next().click();
    }
});
    $('.prev').click(function(){
    if(!$(".clicked").is(".gallerythumbnail:first"))
    {
        $('.clicked').prev().click();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7mUmK/14/)

And if by chance you *do* want it to loop around in end cases

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    if(!$(".clicked").is(".gallerythumbnail:last"))
    {
        $('.clicked').next().click();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".gallerythumbnail:first").click();
    }
});
    $('.prev').click(function(){
    if(!$(".clicked").is(".gallerythumbnail:first"))
    {
        $('.clicked').prev().click();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".gallerythumbnail:last").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for handle the error in first/last img. that should be the answer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard added looping

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger the next/prev image element click of `.clicked` element on next/prev click button respectively.try this:

```
 $('.next').click(function(){
  if($('.clicked').next().is(':last'))
    $('.clicked').next().click();
 });
 $('.prev').click(function(){
  if($('.clicked').prev().is(':first'))
    $('.clicked').prev().click();
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7mUmK/27/)**

Comment: Works great unless you're on the first image and click Prev or on the last and click Next. Then it goes nuts on you.

Comment: @PatrickQ: its should work that way only unless OP want it to be circular.

Comment: Umm… I don't think I'd ever say that something "should" lock up your browser before it realizes that you're in infinite recursion and stops itself. I'm not saying that it "should" loop around circular, but it sure shouldn't behave the way it does.

Comment: @PatrickQ if you're not in favor of Milind's answer write one the way that you think it should be.

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm agree with you, if you stop in the first/last img and click the buttons the console will explode, I think It is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/7mUmK/28/

```
$(".thumbs_img  a").click(function(e){
    var c = $(this).attr('class');
    skipImg(c);
    e.preventDefault();
});


function skipImg(c){
    var sel = $('img.clicked'),
        l = $('.thumbs_img img').length,
        n;
    if( c == "next"){
        n = $('.clicked').next();
        if(n.index() > l){
           n = $('.thumbs_img img').eq(0);
        }
    }else{
        n = $('.clicked').prev();
        if(n.index() <= 0){
            n = $('.thumbs_img img').eq(l - 1);
        }
    }
    n.addClass('clicked');
    sel.removeClass('clicked');
   //here call a function to change big img
}
```